# Sharepoint online not indexing Publishing Pages

Tags: sharepoint-online, search-results, enterprise-search, crawling, index-component

I have a publishing site containing pages with custom pages page layout and custom content type. All the documents, and site pages are appearing on search results but it is not showing results from Publishing "Pages" library.

Comment: Is the site crawlable? Is the list crawlable? Are items from the list in the crawl log?

Comment: Site is crawlable. But I am not sure where to see crawl logs on SharePoint Online

Comment: Crawl log: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/svarukala/2017/08/09/how-to-download-or-view-sharepoint-online-search-crawl-logs-using-security-compliance-center/

Comment: you can also use the "SQT" (Search query tool) to search for a certain url... This will allow you to find all content in the index.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an issue going on with SharePoint online because of which `.aspx` pages are not getting indexed.

Expected time for a fix is tomorrow.

It is visible in the Admin center.

You need Admin credentials to check it.

Go to `Admin Center > Service Health` and check the SharePoint online advisory

The URL for that is :

```
https://admin.microsoft.com/AdminPortal/Home#/servicehealth
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Yes, I had contacted the Microsoft they also confirmed the same..!! Any ways thanks !!